# persisting a bean failed and throw ValidationException [spring MVC]

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, annotations, entitymanager

I am trying to add a new count to the database and I should be sur that the username is unique, so I create a custom validator, but it throw an Exception :

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.EChallenge.model.Compte entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:77)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:192)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:152)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:61)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1191)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1257)
org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
com.EChallenge.dao.CompteDaoImplementation.finfByUserName(CompteDaoImplementation.java:41)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy261.finfByUserName(Unknown Source)
com.EChallenge.service.CompteServiceImplementation.nomUtilisateurExiste(CompteServiceImplementation.java:44)
com.EChallenge.validateur.NomUtilisateurUniqueValidator.isValid(NomUtilisateurUniqueValidator.java:32)
com.EChallenge.validateur.NomUtilisateurUniqueValidator.isValid(NomUtilisateurUniqueValidator.java:1)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:448)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:127)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:87)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:73)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:592)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:490)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:454)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:406)
org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:204)
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:137)
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95)
org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:214)
org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:92)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy258.persist(Unknown Source)
com.EChallenge.dao.AbstractDao.persist(AbstractDao.java:40)
com.EChallenge.dao.CompteDaoImplementation.add(CompteDaoImplementation.java:16)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy261.add(Unknown Source)
com.EChallenge.service.CompteServiceImplementation.add(CompteServiceImplementation.java:21)
com.EChallenge.controller.Inscription.EnregistrerDeveloppeur(Inscription.java:66)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

my Challenger bean is

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "CHALLENGER")
public class Challenger {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "challengerId")
private int challengerId;


@Valid
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "compteId")
private Compte compte;
```

and here is my count bean is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPTE")
public class Compte {
@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "compteId")
private int compteId;


@NotEmpty
@NomUtilisateurUnique
@Column(name = "nomUtilisateur")
private String nomUtilisateur;
```

and my validator class is

```
public boolean isValid(String nomUtilisateur, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
    if(nomUtilisateur == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if(!compteService.nomUtilisateurExiste(nomUtilisateur)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and here is my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/InscriptionDeveloppeur", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String EnregistrerDeveloppeur (@Valid @ModelAttribute("developpeur") Developpeur developpeur,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "InscriptionDeveloppeur";
    }

    compte.add(developpeur.getCompte());
    dev.add(developpeur);   
    return "redirect:/Authentification";
}
```

I have no idea why it consider the Id of 'COMPTE' is Null, what am I doing wrong please i need your help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: because you dont have cascade PERSIST set?

Comment: Can you explain more please because i am new in JEE

Comment: Any JPA tutorial will tell you about the OneToOne annotation and the cascadeType setting, so that the related object is persisted when you persist the one passed to em.persist. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/annotations.html#OneToOne

Comment: i have already add this but nothing changed, and my mapping is working fine any other ideas, and thank you.

Comment: Step 1 in debugging .... look in the LOG!